# What are the 50 instances of SQL SERVER Express 2014?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web

http://sqlknowledge.com/2014/04/sql-2014-express-edition-limitations/

On this website, the author says SQL Server express 2014's Max instance per server is 50. Does it mean only 50 users can connect to the server, or access the server at the same time?
So, if I'm building a data-driven website(using ASP.NET C#) that inserts/retrieves data from SQL Server 2014 express, only 50 users can log onto my website at the same time??

Thanks

Comment: No that is not the max number of users. That is the max number of sql server instances.

Comment: so what exactly are the instances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the maximum number of SQL server installations (instances) on a single server is 50. Typically, you will only use 1 instance for an application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another question. On what occasion someone would do multiple server installations on a single computer?

Comment: @user3358347: You can have multiple instances to have different versions of SQL Server, or if you want them isolated from each other.

Comment: One such occasion is when you want to install both a standard SQL server instance and a SQL express instance on the same machine. Basically, instances are a way to segregate groups of databases into different groups and/or to make the databases run independently of one another.

Comment: @user3358347 Also some applications use SQL Server as their datastorage and don't want other applications to mess with the instance, so they will install their own. This way they can control the entire security model and there won't be any clashes with user accounts etc.

Answer (score 1):

An Instance of a SQL Server on a PC/Computer/Server means when you inserted the CD and installed SQL Server (Application) on the machine.

Each time you Install SQL Server (Application) on a PC it installs an INSTANCE of SQL Server.

Each time you install an Instance you have to give it a Name. It will be the Instance name.

When you are installing SQL Server it gives you the option of giving it a Name or pick the Default name for the installation.

If it is a Default instance you will connect to it by using only the `MachineName`.

If it is a Named Instance you will connect it to using the `MachineName\InstanceName`.

There can be only ONE Default Instance of SQL Server on a machine and Multiple Named instances (in Sql Server 2014 case 49) and obviously one named instance.

The maximum number of user to connect to SQL Server can be checked by looking at

1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and click Properties.
2. Click the Connections node.
3. Under Connections, in the Max number of concurrent connections

**Important Note**

SQL Server being a resource hungry monster, it is best to keep only one instance of sql server on a machine. Otherwise your one instance of SQL Server can starve other instances of resources (memory, CPU) .